# How can I convert a tar encoded file into a terraform variable?

Tags: terraform, tar, data-conversion

I'm trying to copy a license file onto an instance using a provisioner in terraform.

I'm trying to minimize the amount of files in my directory, so I would like to avoid having any extra files. For other files, I was able to pass it to the destination using content as opposed to source in a terraform provisioner. However, since the file I'm trying to copy is a tar archive, I can't find a way to convert it into a string format that can be expressed as a value for content.

It also needs to be decoded using terraform's language so that it can be read properly by the VM. This unfortunately limits my options to terraform's decoding functions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/base64decode.html)

I was thinking my best option was to try to encode it into base64, but I couldn't find a way to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way.

First encode your tar file into [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and save to parameter store

```
cat <tar_file>.tar |base64 -w0 |tee output.txt
```

> Notes: `-w0` can make sure the output in one line

Then save the base64 hash to [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) as string or secure string, for example, name it as `license_key`

Then you can work in terraform to get it

```
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "foo" {
  name = "license_key"
}

locals {
  license = base64encode(data.aws_ssm_parameter.foo.value)
}

output "license" {
  value = local.license
}
```

> codes are for terraform 0.12.x

The rest for using provisioner in terraform, you should know how to do that.

**Above codes are not tested, I just provide the idea for you.**